# Errors while installing Python packages with Pip

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

Im trying to install Python packages **enum** and **Treedict** with Pip. Python is v. 3.7.3 and Pip is v. 19.1.1. Im using PyCharm as my IDE.

I got following error messages:
Treedict:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "...\pycharm-packaging\treedict\setup.py", 
line 96
    print "+++++++++++++++++++"
                              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("+++++++++++++++++++")?
```

enum:

```
Collecting enum
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/a0/32e1d5a21b703f600183e205aafc6773577e16429af5ad3c3f9b956b07ca/enum-0.4.7.tar.gz

ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import distutils.core
  File "...\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 16, in <module>
    from distutils.dist import Distribution
  File "...\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 9, in <module>
    import re
  File "...\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 143, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag

ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in ...\pip-install-lke25k9k\treedict\
```

Some packages, such as numpy and cython installed succesfully but these somehow, do not. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What actual command were you running? Seems that `python` is a 2.7 version and not 3.7.

Comment: python -m pip install treedict. Python should point to a version 3.7 if not mistaken. python -V returns Python 3.7.3. But I also have v. 2.7 on my pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TreeDict's last release was in 2013](https://pypi.org/project/treedict/#history). It's not compatible with Python 3 and therefore cannot be installed. (The errors show that it's using invalid `print` syntax, for example.)

You probably also don't need to install `enum`. There is a [Q&A at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43124775/435093) related to this issue. The solution seems to be to either uninstall the `enum34` package – if installed – or make sure that nothing else is overriding your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.